# Beats Audio on HTC phones

Tags: htc-desire, htc-one-x, htc

Do Beats Audio activate if I use wireless headphones/earbuds? Thank you very much. It will be best if it does work on HTC one X or desire X.

Answer (score 0):

When you plug in the beats audio enhancement self starts, you can see a beats logo on top left on your notification panel. You can swipe down the notification panel and uncheck the tick next to it to disable / re-enable it.

Thats on HTC Desire X

Answer (score 0):

Beats audio automatically enables (if set to enable) if you play media.